# Java inline optimization is this correct?

Tags: java, oop, optimization

so I just saw this code at work, and the author told me it's for inline optimization.

```
Class Test{
...
void init(){
   //sets variables, call functions, etc
} 
...
}
```

then he calls it in main like this

```
Test t=new Test();
t.init();
```

Instead of having a default constructor with the code from init() in it. He told me it's for inline optimization. 
Is this correct? How is it faster? where do I read up about this?

Comment: Nothing optimize anything in your code..

Comment: How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Utter nonsense -- the author is a fool

Comment: [See here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/10/java-class-instance-initializers/) for some subtleties with constructors and initializers. (Even though this Q is about calling "helper" or worker methods after the default constructor, it is is slightly relevant.) Moving *all* the work a named constructor could be doing with pseudo-bean init or setter methods is... not advisable.

Comment: the results of the init() are not published with the same strict requirements as the constructor, on the other hand all null-values would be published strictly. So its doubtfull it helps performance, it surely has nothing to do with inlining.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not faster. It seems to be predicated on the assumption that a method can be inlined but a constructor can't. Unfortunately that's nonsense, so the entire point of it goes out the window.

Even if this were faster, it would almost certainly be a bad idea. Code should not be optimised at the expense of readability, except in extreme circumstances where every last CPU cycle is critical, and in that case you're unlikely to be using Java.

In fact, this is worse than just being harder to read. The next refactoring will inevitably be for the `Test` constructor to call the `init()` method, so that it doesn't always have to be done manually (and doing it manually is a pain and a potential source of bugs if it gets forgotten); and it is bad practice if a constructor calls a method that can be overridden, because a subclass might inadvertently change what happens at construction time when the superclass constructor is called (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) for more details). When this happens, a subclass of `Test` within the same package will be able to override the `init()` method, and then when the subclass invokes `super()`, either implicitly or explicitly, the superclass's constructor will end up calling the *overridden* `init()`. (This particular problem could be got rid of by declaring `init()` to be `private`.)

Don't do it.

Comment: What if there were 2 constructors? It would be easier to read if both called the init method

Comment: _Unless_ the `init` method is doing anything multithreaded (such as registering `this` as a listener to some other thread, starting a new thread that knows about `this`, etc), in which case you _must_ keep `init()` separate for thread safety.

Comment: @JClassic One nice way to handle that is by making one "canonical" constructor (possibly private, if need be) and having the other constructors invoke it via `this(someArg, anotherArg, maybeSomeArg + 42)`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you have anything to optimize. That being said, I do not think that it is a good idea at a design phase either because class initialization is something which each class must do on its own. Placing such behaviour in a seperate method which:

1. Has to be called separately
2. Can, in turn be also overridden

Is something which is not usually recommended.